# Alexa Skills - Intent being invoked without the correct utterance

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-interaction-model

So I'm creating an Alexa skill using the Alexa Developer Console with a Python backend. I've just started a new skill, with the 'Hello World' template, so it has the default utterances of hi, hello, etc.

When testing the skill, using the Alexa Simulator, I input the word 'test' and it invoked the HelloWorldIntent even though the word 'test' is not an utterance for that intent. Is there a way to make it so that an intent can ONLY be invoked by the utterances?

EDIT:
I have the built-in FallBackIntent enabled, but this doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**You have one option available for all English locales and `de-DE` local:**.
[Adjust AMAZON.FallbackIntent sensitivity](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/standard-built-in-intents.html#adjust-sensitivity)

It is available in the Intents list
[image]

> If AMAZON.FallbackIntent is enabled for a skill, default sensitivity value is set to 'LOW'. As the sensitivity for a skill is increased, more customer utterances that are not supported by your skill's custom intents will be captured by AMAZON.FallbackIntent. Learn more about skill's model sensitivity tuning.

For all other locales, this is not available and it might trigger other intents. Usually, that's not an issue because your skill should let the users know what they can do.